# angular 2 - cannot templatize table styles

Tags: angular

I have a table component which I give some settings, like the column widths, but they don't seem to end up in the final rendered html

table template: (not sure of the syntax)

```
<div *ngIf="settings">
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let column of settings.columns" [style.width]="column.width+'px'">
                <span>{{ column.name }}</span>
            </th>
    ...
```

table component :

```
...    

export class DataTableComponent {

    @Input() settings: any;

  ...
```

parent template (using the table):

```
<my-datatable [settings]="tableSettings" ></my-datatable>
```

parent component (in the constructor)

```
           this.tableSettings = {
                        columns: [
                            { name: this.trads["ID"], value: 'id', width: "30px", insertable: false },
                            { name: this.trads["FirstName"], value: 'firstname', width: "100px", insertable: true },
                            { name: this.trads["LastName"], value: 'lastname', width: "100px", insertable: true },
                            { name: this.trads["Email"], value: 'email', width: "100px", insertable: true },
                        ]
                    };
```

This looks correct but I can't make it work. Any idea?

Comment: looks like you'll get a repetition of the 'px' string (eg 30pxpx) as the code stands now, so the widths will be not what you want!

Comment: damned... how could I forget that one...thanks